# Welcome back banner isn't centered

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, notification-bar

The 'Welcome Back' banner isn't centered:

> [image]

Here's another example on Physics.SE:

> [image]

I'm currently on Chrome v64.0.3282.140, but I reproduced in Safari 11:

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thank you.

As part of our "make our CSS slightly less horrible" project, we finally switched to `box-sizing: border-box` as the default (even the CSSWG these days [thinks that should have been the default from the start](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/mistakes)). This notification bar is one of the places we missed where this requires a change.